# Xcode modules enabled in settings, but still can't use @import

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In settings, "Enable Modules" is set to Yes:

[image: Enable Modules]

And yet I still get the error: "Use of '@import' when modules are disabled."

[image: Error]

This is on a project I'm updating to use Modules, not a new project (works fine in a new project).

Are there conditions where Xcode falls back to includes instead of using modules?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One place that modules aren't available is in Objective-C++ code (`.mm` file extension), which is notable for projects communicating between C/C++ and Objective-C.

If you use the `@import` syntax in an Objective-C++ file, you get the same error you reported ("Use of '@import' when modules are disabled").

The [Clang docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#objective-c-import-declaration) say:

> At present, there is no C or C++ syntax for import declarations. Clang will track the modules proposal in the C++ committee.

which I take to be referring to this unavailability.

Comment: Does it mean it's not enable to compile a module with Objective-C++ code?